# ADSL and Cable modem connected to same SWITCH?

Tags: networking, switch, cable-modem, dsl-modem, iptv

I have had ADSL and IPTV using the ADSL connection for quite long time. Recently I was offered much faster internet connection using cable modem. I Have all my devices (IPTV box, ps4, Desktop PC... etc) connected to a linksys Switch. IPTV box has to use the connection through ADSL modem, but I would like rest of my devices to use the faster cable modem connection. Can I connect both ADSL modem and Cable modem to the same linksys switch and would IPTV still work? My IPTV box is Motorola VIP 1963.

Comment: Can you provide the model # of the switch? You usually use a dual wan router here for either fail-over or load balancing/Multiple gateway's.

Comment: Model is Linksys LGS108

Comment: If I connect the cable modem to the same switch, does everything just stop working then?

Comment: How about disabling DHCP in the cable modem and setting it's IP as gateway manually for those devices that I want to use the faster internet it provides?

Comment: Add the model numbers of the ADSL modem, and cable modem to your question.

Comment: ADSL modem is Thomson TG789 and it came with the IPTV service. Cable modem is Technicolor TC7230.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions I'm about to give are more of a workaround, or hack. The right way to do this has some serious benefits over the workaround.

A dual wan router would allow you to:

1. Share both connections with all the devices.
2. When a link fails, all devices will dynamically switch to the other link without intervention.
3. Divide the bandwidth equally with traffic policies, to force specific traffic out the connection you prefer for it.
4. Allow for multiple ways to reach your network from the internet, for vpns, remote desktop, file sharing, etc.
5. Provides centralized administration for both connections.

The work around can be thought of as a static configuration as opposed to dynamic.

You won't be able to share the two connections dynamically or traffic based. You will have to choose what client devices connect to what ISP devices.

If a link fails, you will have to reconfigure the client configurations, and probably have to mess around with the configuration for the ISP devices.

That being said, PFsense is a open based routing platform (it's free!). It would work very well for this role, and in most scenarios can be installed on older hardware. (Like an old PC tower or laptop)

Because both ISP devices are technically combo devices, (internally a modem, router, switch) you would set the ADSL modem local IP address to (10.10.10.1 255.255.255.0) & disable DHCP on this modem for the LAN.

On the cable modem, you would set it to something distinguishable from the first like, (192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0) DHCP on this router should be on. Now plug both the ADSL modem, and cable modem into your switch. Statically set your TV IP address to "10.10.10.100", netmask "255.255.255.0", gatway/DNS = "10.10.10.1".

Now, any client device that is set to receive a DHCP IP address will get an address from the cable modem and use that connection. If you want a device to use the ADSL connection, set the client IP address statically to the 10.10.10.x subnet with the gateway/DNS pointing to 10.10.10.1

I can't stress to you enough, how much better this will be with a router controlling the two connections.

Let me know how this works out for you.

Comment: I probably would have to do other way around because my Motorola IPTV box is provided by the IPTV service provider and it is the onli device that does not allow me to change any network settings. At least I have always assumed it needs DHCP turned on, but I have not tried turning it off.

Comment: It would make things easier, especially if it's only your IPtv using ADSL. If you can't it shouldn't matter if you reversed the instructions